# How could I randomly choose between different game-objects in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to be able to have differently sized platforms spawn randomly in-game, but I don't know how to do so.

This is the code I have written so far;

```
    void Update () 
    {
        if (transform.position.x < generationPoint.position.x) 
        {
            platformHeight = Random.Range(platformHeightMax,platformHeightMin);

            distanceBetween = Random.Range(distanceBetweenMin, distanceBetweenMax);

            transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x + platformWidth + distanceBetween, platformHeight, transform.position.z);

            Instantiate (thePlatforms[UnityEngine.Random.Range] , transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Random.Range(platformHeightMax,platformHeightMin);` Aren't these variables the wrong way around?

Comment: Are you trying to choose between 2 random `GameObjects` or are you trying to randomly change the scale of the spawn `GameObjects` your title makes it sound like you want to choose between random objects, your post makes it sound like you just want to change the size of an object.

Comment: You're changing the transform.position of your Platform_Generator object, by the way. You want to be setting the position of the object you're instantiating. Also, you're setting the instantiated objects rotation to the Platform_Generators rotation.. If you want to keep the prefabs rotation just use Quaternion.Identity

Comment: Your code hints at choosing a random gameobject in a list of gameobjects, I am sure if you look into the parameters of Random.Range, and you like at the methods, and public variables available to you in thePlatforms, you can figure out what should go in the line `thePlatforms[UnityEngine.Random.Range]`

Comment: @Eddge I was wondering that as well. How does this code not throw an error?

Comment: @Eddge I'm not sure. That sounds like a fine line between breaking the "Separation of concerns" principle.. But to each their own.

Comment: @Eddge I'm not sure what you mean by separate script. Everything I suggested could be done within the same script, but without moving the object it is attached to. He essentially has made an object pooling system. The system should be concerned with pooling the objects and setting their positions/rotations/scale, not messing around with its own properties. By doing so you're actually adding a step since the instantiated object will still have to receive those values regardless.

Comment: @BrandonMiller Thanks for the chat I will be cleaning up my comments so not to spam this question.

Comment: @Eddge Transform is not stored the way you think. Here's a snippet from Unity themselves: `Setting the position or rotation of a transform causes an internal OnTransformChanged event to propagate to all of that transform's children. This means that it's relatively expensive to set a transform's position and rotation values, especially in transforms that have many children. The transform's world position is calculated every time we call Transform.position.`. While it (probably) doesn't have any children, it's still more expensive since you're forcing Unity to do unnecessary calculations.

Comment: @BrandonMiller Thanks for sharing that, but the cost is still relatively inexpensive, you will not see a difference in a runtime application doing it either way.

Comment: @Eddge i am trying randomly choose between 5 game objects to make the endless runner game more difficult by having the player jump onto different sized platforms

Comment: @Callum you know how many objects are in your array correct?  So, why don't you put that information into  `Instantiate (thePlatforms[UnityEngine.Random.Range(someNumber here, another number here)] , transform.position, transform.rotation);`

Comment: @Eddge I have all the different platform sizes as separate objects within unity, i want to be able to randomly have the different platforms to be generated in front of the player to make the game more challenging. sorry for being so unclear.